# WSO2 ESB ssl endpoint "Read timed out"

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a new proxy service with an endpoint secured by ssl.the cert of endpoint is imported in client-truststore.jks, it seems that everything is fine when I add endpoint by url and test it by hit the test button.

```
"Successfully connected to https://XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXService.asmx?wsdl"
```

but when I make a pass through proxy based on this endpoint I get the read timed out response on call of every method of this proxy service, this is wso2carbon.log of this:

```
TID: [-1234] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2015-07-24 11:47:43,690]  INFO  {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  
Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://XXXXXXXX:8284/services/XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache
```

I test the endpoint by tryit (in Tools section) but it dose not work! It's not loaded.
but I can get proper response when I call:

```
curl -k -X POST https://XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXService.asmx -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/apply""  --data-binary @request.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SOAP action. It should be the name of the method you need to call in the end point. Your SOAP action seems to be invalid one.

Also if it is not an wsdl endpoint you may remove ?wsdl part from the ep.

Comment: I test the proxy service by wso2 tryIt tool, so you mean tryIt sends invalid soapAction?!!
& I checked both with ?wsdl and without it for endpoint url and the result is same.

Comment: I should say again that curl command works fine(with -k to ignore ssl).

Comment: any idea, @Ravindra?!

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess the reason is SOAP action.Please open debug log . 
   In esb_home/repository/conf/log4j.properties file.

   ```
   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
   ```

   You will see something like below in the WSO2/wso2 developer-studio
   console.**Please check the host is your back end service host.**

   ```
   DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-18 >> POST XXXXXXXXXService.asmx HTTP/1.1
   DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-18 >> SOAPAction: "XXXXXXXX
   DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-18 >> Content-Type: application/soap+xml
   DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-18 >> Content-Length: 2017
   DEBUG - headers http-outgoing-18 >> Host: XXXXXXXX
   ```
2. I'm assuming your back end service use the SOAP12, because i see you
   use WSO2 soap12 endpoint. In SOAP12, soap action will in
   `Content-Type`. like:

   ```
   Content-Type: application/soap+xml, action="XXXXXX"
   ```

please check does WSO2 send the SOAP action to back end service. Also have look at on Content-Type: **application/soap+xml**

if you back end service using `WS-ADDRESSING` , you need also check
    debug header info for WS-ADDRESSING.

3. .If you set endpoint format as "SOAP12", you may meet the following
   bug--missing soap action: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3047
4. wso2 default using HTTP 1.1 with Transfer-Encoding: chunked when
   call back end endpoint. please check your back end service, you may
   use below property:

   ```
   <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   ```
5. if you back end service use the  `WS-ADDRESSING`,you may use below property:

   ```
   <property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @James for you reply.
this is my debug info:
` >> POST /XXXXXXXXXService.asmx?wsdl HTTP/1.1 {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers}
  >> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers}
  >> SOAPAction: "https://XXXXXXXXX/apply" {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers}
  >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers}
  >> Host: XXXXXXXXX:443 {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers}`
everything is ok except Content-Type.

Comment: The endpoint has both of Soap11 and Soap12, how can I force wsoe esb to use Soap11 of endpoint?

Comment: @Meysam Could you please call you back end service by using SOAP UI or SOA test and compare SOAP header with WSO2 debug header info. Make sue you back end service support  chunked. You mean you want WSO2 send SOAP11 to back end service? the you need add format="soap11" in your endpoint mediator. And also change your endpoint without ?wsdl.

Comment: I call back end service by SoapUI end the diffs are:
1. the path of POST is complete:
POST 'ht tps://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXService.asmx HTTP/1.1'
2.there is no 443 port after Host name.
3.Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

Comment: I set DISABLE_CHUNKING true but the Transfer-Encoding is still "chunked "!

Comment: @Meysam it's doesn't matter. there is no 443 port after Host name in SOAP UI. Could you check the SOAPAction and Content-Type in SOAP UI. And compare the whole headers. And also compare the soap messages, I think you can also see the SOAP mesages in debug info.

Comment: when I call soap11 endpoint of proxy service from TryIt, The SoapAction and Content-Type are the same as SoapUI.
SoapMessage are same too!

Comment: if SoapAction has a problem it can't be cause of timeout exception right? service should say something about wrong action name or something like that.

Comment: @Meysam i meet this error before, that beacuse my back end service using WS-ADDRESSING and when i check the debug log, i found WSO2 ignore my WS- ADDRESS in header, so i never have chance to call in the back end service. It's return time-out error. but you can try to increase the wso2 call time.

Comment: I can't find any use of ws-addressing in WSDL so maybe this not the cause of problem,BTW I think about two major point that can make the problem:
1: I said that back end service has both soap 11 and 12 version of interfaces but I found that I can't call 1.2 from SoapUI maybe I should say to esb that ignore 1.2. in endpoint definition I use soap1.1 and url without ?wsdl but stil dose not work!                 2.the back end service use https and maybe there is something wrong about that.I import certification in client_truststore and test was ok but proxy is not working yet!

Comment: and one more thing, my esb version is 4.5, maybe I should upgrade my esb?!!:) :(

Comment: @Meysam if you import SSL cert of your back end service into client-truststore, then HTTPS back end service should fine. BTW, the WS- ADDRESS using xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing". I ready suggest you look into the WSO2 esb debug info. And compare the http header and soap header/body with you soap UI. If you found different, try to use soap UI simulate WSO2 info and check does same error return. I know the wso2 debug info is hard to check but important info in there. And if you use wso2 developer-studio, the debug info may have good format.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I compare the header but unfortunately I can't find any difference there(I sent you some information in previous comments).
For now I suggest to backend service provider team to change their service for more test.